# Drupal 7 - 24 hour event reminder

Tags: sql, events, drupal, date

I'm looking to write a script that will send an email reminder to all users who have subscribed to an event (node) using the event date that is set for each event.

Firstly, how often do you think I should run the cron? I was thinking of running it hourly and getting all events where the event date is greater than DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) and less than DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 HOUR). Does this sound correct?

The query i'm running is the following, although its not returning any events even though I have set an event up so that it starts just after 24 hours from now.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->join('field_data_field_date', 'd', 'n.nid = d.entity_id');

$query
->condition('n.type', 'event', '=')
->condition('d.field_date_value', 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)', '>')
->condition('d.field_date_value', 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 HOUR)', '<')
->fields('n')
->fields('d')
;
```

Any idea what the problem with this is or if there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding complex expressions doesn't work quite like that with the database API, you need to use the [`addExpression()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQueryInterface%3A%3AaddExpression/7) method:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n')
  ->fields('d');

$query->join('field_data_field_date', 'd', 'n.nid = d.entity_id');

$query->addExpression('d.field_date_value > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)');
$query->addExpression('d.field_date_value < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 HOUR)');
```